# setTimeOut with JQuery function .live()

Tags: jquery, live, settimeout

I have this:

```
function toggle() {
    $('#clbttn').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#msg').fadeOut('fast');
    setTimeout(function() { $('#msg').remove(); $('#clbttn').remove(); }, 200);
}
$('#clbttn').live('click', toggle());
```

And as a result I have this:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #clbttn has no method 'apply'

Does anybody know what I should do?

Comment: You are passing the **return value** (which is *not* a function) of `toggle` to `live`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should change `toggle()` to `toggle`, since the former is a function call.

```
$('#clbttn').live('click', toggle);
```

Comment: Yeah, it works. Thank you! But I still have a question... Why was it working OK for a month? It's really strange.

Answer (score 1):

As Jason said, `live` is deprecated, and should be replaced with `on`.  But, do **not** just do this:

```
$('#clbttn').on('click', toggle);
```

That will not work with dynamically added content, since it will not set up a delegated event handler.  The above would be equivalent to

```
$('#clbttn').bind('click', toggle);
```

To use `on` with dynamically added content, you want:

```
$(document).on('click', '#clbttn', toggle);
```

This will tell jQuery to listen to all clicks bubbling up to the document's root, and fire the toggle function when the click comes from an element with an id of `clbttn`.  If you know this element will only ever be in, say, a div with id `foo`, you could more efficiently write this as

```
$("#foo").on('click', '#clbttn', toggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

live is obsolete, jquery recommends using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().
>
> This method provides a means to attach delegated event handlers to the
>   document element of a page, which simplifies the use of event handlers
>   when content is dynamically added to a page. See the discussion of
>   direct versus delegated events in the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for more
>   information.